# Laravel миграции смена типа таблицы (InnoDB -> MyISAM)

Tags: php, laravel, миграция

До версии **MySQL 5.6+** тип таблиц `InnoDB` не поддерживает полнотекстовый поиск. Обновить версию MySQL на сервере - нет возможности, но требуется организовать полнотекстовый поиск.

Как в **Laravel** миграции сменить тип существующей таблицы с `InnoDB` на `MyISAM` без потери данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартными методами **Laravel** миграций не получится сменить тип таблицы. Но, это можно сделать при помощи выполнения следующего запроса: `ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = MyISAM`.

Перед тем как сменить тип таблицы, нужно удалить все **foreign keys** в данной таблице, а также все ссылающиеся внешние ключи из других таблиц на данную.

**Пример миграции:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UpdateUsersProfileSetTableEngineMyisam extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('users_profile_user_id_foreign');
        });
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users_profile ENGINE = MyISAM');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users_profile ENGINE = InnoDB');
        Schema::table('users_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }
}
```

Данный метод подходит и для обратной смены типа таблицы с `MyISAM -> InnoDB`.